# Receive service bus message queue/topics in web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azureservicebus

I am working on a microservice based application in azure. My requirement is I had a service bus and I need to consume that service bus message in web api. Currently I implemented through azure functions, but my company asked to use api. Is it possible?, If possible please show me how to do it

Comment: Yes. Use an `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService`.

Comment: Can you please provide me any tutorial?. How this will process if i receive more message at a time?

Comment: Look up how to connect to a `ServiceBus`, then put that inside of the `ExecuteAsync` method of the [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). Then poll from within the `ExecuteAsync` method until the `CancellationToken` is set.

Comment: Thank you, but again instead of functions we are using background service. So is there any other way that I can call message directly from a api controller?

Comment: Could you please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read , May it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create Background service to listen to message from service bus queue.
Below are few key points that needs to be noted:

- *Background task that runs on a timer.*
- *Hosted service that activates a scoped service. The scoped service can use dependency injection (DI).*
- *Queued background tasks that run sequentially.*

App Settings:

```
1.  {
2.  "AppSettings": {
3.  "QueueConnectionString": "<replace your RootManageSharedAccessKey here>",
4.  "QueueName": "order-queue"
5.  }
6.  }
```

You can refer to c-sharpcorner [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-azure-service-bus-queues-asp-net-core-background-services/) for step by step process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to get a simple message.

```js
ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient("Endpoint=sb://yourservicesbusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=Your_SharedAccess");

var receiver = client.CreateReceiver("Your Queue");

var message = await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1);

string ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message.FirstOrDefault().Body);

Console.WriteLine("Received Single Message: " + ascii);

await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message.FirstOrDefault());
```

I did some modifications from this post
https://ciaranodonnell.dev/posts/receiving-from-azure-servicebus/